# Функция одобрения комментариев

Tags: python, django, orm

Я абсолютный новичок в программировании.
Пытаюсь написать функцию одобрения комментария, чтобы после принятия, он отображался под постом. Неодобренные комменты отображаются на отдельной странице пользователям чьим постам они были написаны.

функция:

```
def approve(request, pk):
    # вытаскиваем текущего пользователя
    user = request.user
    # вытаскиваем коммент по pk, неодобренный
    coms = Comment.objects.get(pk=pk, is_accepted=False)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # меняем значение
        coms.is_accepted = True
        # привязываем к юзеру
        coms.user = request.user
        # сохраняем в БД
        coms.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('mypage'))
    return render(request, 'mypage.html', {'coms': coms})
```

урлы:

```
path('approve/<int:pk>/', approve, name='approve')
```

тэмплейт:

```
<a href="{% url 'approve' comment.id %}">Опубликовать</a>
```

Данные в БД не идут, пыталась еще так реализовать, но не получается

```
def approve(request, pk):
    # вытаскиваем  неодобренные комменты юзера
    coms = Comment.objects.filter(post__author=request.user, is_accepted=False)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for x in coms:
            Comment.objects.filter(pk=int(x)).update(is_accepted=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('posts'))
    return render(request, 'mypage.html', {'coms': coms})
```

Comment: А где вы кидаете post запрос?

Comment: Всмысле? объясните подробнее, пожалуйста 

Comment: Где вы посылаете на сервер post запрос? Когда человек переходит по ссылке - он хочет получить html сайта (т.е GET запрос), а когда человек отправляет форму (например пишет комментарий) должен отправляться post запрос

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю суть вопроса - мне необходимо, чтобы автор поста мог одобрять или удалять комментарии к его посту прежде чем они будут опубликованы. Функции написания комментария и его удаления работают. я пытаюсь создать возможность нажатием на кнопку "Опубликовать" - менять is_accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False) на is_accepted=True

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял - вам нужно при нажатии на кнопку отправлять post запрос на сервер и создать комментарий. Это нужно делать не ссылкой, а, например, через js и JQuerry:

```
<button id="sendCommentButton">Отправить</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

```
$("#sendCommentButton").on("click", function (_) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: location.href,
        data: {
            "user_id": "user_id",
            "content": "комментарий"
        },
        headers: {
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'X-CSRFToken': "csrfToken"
        },
        success: function (data, _) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    })
})
```

Или более кустарно, но через html:

```
<form action="{{ request.path }}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="user_id" name="user_id">
    <input type="hidden" value="комментарий" name="content"> <!-- В таких input можно хранить и передавать в django данные -->
    <button type="submit">Оправить</button>
</form>
```

И в django:

```
content = request.POST.get("content")
user_id= request.POST.get("user_id")
```

Или как в вашем случае:

```
comment_id = request.POST.get("comment_id")
comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=comment_id, is_accepted=False)
if request.method == 'POST':
   comment.is_accepted = True
   comment.user = request.user
   comment.save()
...
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваше участие! Мне нужно не создать комментарий, а создать функцию его одобрения/подтверждения. Функция его создания есть. Принцип такой - Автор создает пост, пользователь пишет под этот пост коммент. Коммент сразу не отображается под постом, но отображается на личной странице автора, где он может или удалить(функция такая у меня есть и работает) или одобрить и тогда он отобразится под постом(такую функцию пытаюсь создать).

Comment: Мой вариант вроде подходит. Насколько я понимаю - сейчас у вас стоит ссылка-кнопка, при нажатии на которую вы ожидаете каких-то изменений в базе. Но этого не происходит, ведь когда человек переходит по ссылке - браузер делает GET запрос к серверу. Это нам не подходит, ведь нам нужен post запрос (`if request.method == 'POST':`). Как раз его можно кинуть теми способами, которые я описал

Comment: Да, именно так )) А объясните, почему тогда мой первый вариант кода не подошел?  из-за отсутствия comment_id = request.POST.get("comment_id")?

Comment: Потому что не срабатывало условие `if request.method == 'POST':`, ведь, как я уже говорил, при переходе по ссылке браузер посылает GET запрос. Конечно можно сделать отдельный endpoint (ссылку), написать отдельную view, в которой убрать условие и тогда, если пользователь переходит по ссылке, изменится статус комментария и человека редиректит обратно, но во первых это колхоз (как по мне), а во вторых у пользователя будет моргать экран при нажатии на кнопку из-за перехода по ссылке и редеректа обратно

Comment: Решила вопрос. Post запрос отправляю через форму ))